# Start Thunderbird in the background to fetch email and close it a few minutes later

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird

In GNU/Linux, how can one start Thunderbird in the background, let it run for a few minutes for emails to be fetched, and close it afterwards?

Comment: Does Thunderbird's "-kill" command-line argument wait until after new messages have been downloaded?  It's undocumented, but perhaps it's worth a try?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Command_Line_Options#Other_options_need_to_be_documented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that thunderbird does not support this functionality, however, there are some discussions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=679592) and [here](http://fixunix.com/mozilla/435314-can-thunderbird-run-background.html) that discuss options for doing this with your window manager/desktop environment.  Essentially by running it minimized, with no system tray icon, etc.

To make it only run for a few minutes, you could start TB from a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/thunderbird &
sleep 300 # 5 minutes
kill $!
```

---

Another option would be to use another program to download your mail for you, and have Thunderbird read the mail from your localdisk.  [OfflineIMAP](https://github.com/jgoerzen/offlineimap/wiki) does a good job if your mail server supports IMAP.  [Fetchmail](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/) is another option that works with POP3, as well.

Comment: I am currently using fetchmail, procmail, and cron. But I was wondering if this could be done, mostly, in one place: Thunderbird. Context switches considered harmful!

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've settled for (thanks to Flimzy's answer) is to use the following script, saved in, say, `$HOME/thunderbird_cron.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/alltray /usr/bin/thunderbird &
sleep 5m
killall thunderbird-bin
```

together with the following `crontab -e` entry

```
0 0 * * * env DISPLAY=:0.0 $HOME/thunderbird_cron.sh
```

to run Thunderbird for 5 minutes once a day at midnight, to fetch emails, and have it closed afterwards.

- `kill $!`, contrary to what's suggested by Danniel Beck, does not work when the script is run by `cron` as `$!` does not return the correct process id there.
- The `env DISPLAY=:0.0` portion will tell `cron` to use the first screen of the current monitor for Thunderbird. It *has* to be there for a GUI application to be run by `cron`.
- [`alltray`](http://alltray.trausch.us) is used to run Thunderbird docked to the tray, effectively making the process of opening and closing invisible to the user.

**Update**: Even if the option "Check for new messages at startup" is selected (under Account Settings/Server Settings) Thunderbird does *not* start downloading new messages until after a folder of your email account is selected. (The version I've tested is 3.1.10 under Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.) To automate this selection at startup, the add-on [`Folderpane Tools`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/folderpane-tools) can be used. (The method discussed at http://kb.mozillazine.org/Show_Inbox_when_starting_Thunderbird does not work.)